# Making Search Bar in angular

Tags: css, angular, angular7, angular8, angular9

I am trying to implement a search bar as attached [Search Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EiVr.png) in angular. How I can efficiently make look wise similar search bar which search for rows in a table on the basis of word entered

Comment: You can use a single input and use its value for a filter pipe.

Comment: how I can make similar structure like this?

Comment: Do you mean similar component? You can search for custom css styles.

Comment: yes I want to make similar one

Comment: You should try it out yourself. Here's something to get started. Create an input box. Remove borders except the bottom part. Give color for the border. Add a good padding value and so on.

Comment: [https://freefrontend.com/css-search-boxes/](https://freefrontend.com/css-search-boxes/). If you don't have issues with how to filter the rows, this is more like a CSS question.